# Python: Filter positive and negative integers from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, math, list-comprehension

Python 3:
Given a string (an equation), return a list of positive and negative integers.
I've tried various regex and list comprehension solutions to no avail.

Given an equation 4+3x or -5+2y or -7y-2x
Returns: [4,3], [-5,2], [-7,-2]

input

```
str = '-7y-2x'
```

output

```
my_list = [-7, -2]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your latest attempt and explain with reference to your code what issues you are having.

Comment: Can't understand why this question got so many downvotes. Yes, the OP haven't shown his efforts, but, at least, he has shown the input and expected output, and the task is quite simple

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple solution using [***re.findall***](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

```
import re

s = '-5+2y'
result = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'-?\d+', s)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[-5, 2]
```

---

`-?\d+` - matches *positive and negative integers*

> Raw string notation (`r"text"`) keeps regular expressions sane.
>   Without it, every backslash ('`\`') in a regular expression would have
>   to be prefixed with another one to escape it

Comment: This works.  I tried re.split() earlier and much longer regex.  So - is optional and digit is not.  What's the 'r' for?

Comment: @JamesGoldstein, *Raw string notation (**r"text"**) keeps regular expressions sane. Without it, every backslash ('\') in a regular expression would have to be prefixed with another one to escape it.*

Comment: A string like `"-3-21"` returns `[-3, -21]`. How would I get `[-3,-2,1]`?

Comment: @MoteZart, in your simple input sample - remove the sign `+`

Answer (score 5):

This regex should solve your problem.

```
[\+\-]?[0-9]+
```

Also, here is some code that goes with it.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[\+\-]?[0-9]+')
nums = [int(k) for k in regex.findall('5-21x')]
```